# IBM Rational Change: Using match operator in query functions with oslc_cm:query

Tags: rest, ibm-rational, oslc

I'm trying to get a list of Change Requests that match certain conditions, some of these conditions are met by using module_comp_version match('*substring*')

I did not find info in OSLC Core Spec 1.0 about 'match' operator. Unfortunately

> oslc.searchTerms

is not working for my case.

I would like to ask is it at all possible query witch match operator and '*substring*'

For queries I'm using the following pattern:

```
http://ip[:port]/change/oslc/db/dbURI/role/User/cr?oslc_cm.query=change:responsible_ccb!="CCB FC" and platform_module_name="SSW" and module_comp_version match "*wk1609*" and crstatus!="duplicate" and crstatus!="rejected" and  release match "*21.0*" &oslc_cm.properties=id,problem_synopsis,module_comp_version
```

This query does work when

```
module_comp_version match "*wk1609* release match "*21.0*"
```

terms are removed. Is it possible to check if a property matches *substring* with oslc_cm?